# Why is the target output in GPT (Andrej Karpathy's course) contains copies of tokens from the input?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, transformer, gpt

The question is based on Andrej Karpathy lecture on training a toy GPT model on Tiny Shakespeare dataset ([youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCc8FmEb1nY&list=PLAqhIrjkxbuWI23v9cThsA9GvCAUhRvKZ&index=10&t=5003s&ab_channel=AndrejKarpathy)). In this model, tokens are single characters with a dictionary of around 60 elements. He creates training and validation datasets as follows

```
def get_batch(...):
    ...
    ix = torch.randint(len(data) - block_size, (batch_size,))
    x = torch.stack([data[i:i+block_size] for i in ix])
    y = torch.stack([data[i+1:i+block_size+1] for i in ix])
    ...
    return x, y
```

Why does he make the target output `y` a sequence of bytes `data[i+1:i+block_size+1]` instead of just a single byte `data[i+block_size+1]`? We are trying to predict the next **single** byte (token) after all.

It looks to me like gpt is trained to predict N (N is the `block_size`) characters of `Y` from N characters of `X`, but the first (N-1) characters in `Y` are just a copy of (N-1) characters in `X`. Surely the NN can be trained to do that, but isn't it a waste of weights and GPU cycles on essentially just copying (N-1) characters?

I ran the script in debugger to confirm that's what indeed happens in training. In the code, after the first breakpoint

```
class GPTLanguageModel(nn.Module):

    ...
    def forward(self, idx, targets=None):
>>>     B, T = idx.shape
```

`idx` is something like `tensor([[ 1, 16, 24, 40, 26, 32, 43, 41],...])`, while `target` is `tensor([[16, 24, 40, 26, 32, 43, 41,  1],...])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Language models predict the next token. At training time, we have an input sequence and we want to train the model to output the next token for each possible sequence prefix **at the same time**, that is, we train the model to generate token 1 based on nothing, token 2 based on token 1, token 3 based on tokens 1 and 2, etc, everything at once. For that, the target output is the same as the input but shifted one position.

Note that, due to the self-attention mask of the Transformer model, the prediction at each position only depends on the previous tokens.